# How to replace element A with B and have B object in variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, selection

I've got something like this:

```
jQuery(this_element).replaceWith('<div>' + jQuery(this_element).html() + '</div>');
```

It works fine but after execution `this_element` still contains old element (that doesn't exist anymore because it has been replaced with `<div>old content</div>`). How can I restore selection in that element or at least grab new element to `this_element` variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the new object separately, then keep a reference to that (jQuery 1.4+):

```
var $B = jQuery('<div/>', { 'html': jQuery(this_element).html() });
jQuery(this_element).replaceWith($B);
this_element = $B;
```

(This uses the [`jQuery(html, props)`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2) method.)

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/nzdPr/1/)

Comment: Great :) And the answer to the second part of my question is this: `var savedSel = rangy.saveSelection(); replace element... rangy.restoreSelection(savedSel);` where I'm using Rangy selection library - http://code.google.com/p/rangy/ (works fine even if element has been replaced with another element).